# Opening and closing solenoid deadbolt with key

Tags: doors, battery, deadbolt

I am starting a project to implement a "smart" lock for my door using Arduino nano, a solenoid deadbolt and a fingerprint reader.
Which on its own works fine, but the whole project will run on a battery and I would require a "failsafe" method to unlock the solenoid deadbolt with a key. How can a solenoid deadbolt be controlled with a key without any current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way is to not use a solenoid to operate the deadbolt but to open the striker plate on the other side. This is called an [electric strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_strike)

[image]
[image]

That way you can use a conventional key operated bolt as a way to open the door when there is no electrical power.

You can buy these strikes for retrofitting to normal types of lock, both mortice locks and surface fitted locks.

Comment: Open the striker plate? I have no idea what that means :-) how can I control a normal deadbolt with an arduino then? :-)

Comment: @John, see above and consult a locksmith - these things are commonplace. I have one lying about somewhere but can't find it at the moment. You can easily control them using an Arduino and a relay shield.